# css3 2nd child of <ul>and so on to get margin-left:20px

Tags: css

I am trying to create a navigation menu and I would like my first `<li>` to line up perfectly with the container above it but I need some spacing to the right of the first `<li>` so I'm trying to do something like:

```
nav .innercontainer ul li:nth-of-type(2n+1){ /*only happen after the first <li>*/
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Thanks these pseudo select elements are confusing as hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the `+` selector:

```
ul > li + li{
    /* all li elements except the first */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nav .innercontainer ul li{
  margin-left:20px;

}

nav .innercontainer ul li:first{
  margin-left:0;

}

if i get it right, its simple this way

Comment: right but you need to write an extra style. Look at shmiddty's implementation

Comment: this one is simple css over css, not math and anything, its a extra line, but the running process is the same...